# Cannot convert from 'const std::string [3]' to 'std::string'

Tags: c++, string, type-conversion

Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

template<int N>
class Arguments
{
protected:
    string arguments[N];
public:
    Arguments(const string(&arg)[N]) : arguments{ arg } {}
    string operator[](const int &i) const { return arguments[i]; }
};

int main()
{
    string arr[3] = { "arg1", "arg2", "arg3" };
    Arguments<3> args(arr);

    cout << args[2];

    return 0;
}
```

This is the error i get:

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   C2440   'initializing': cannot convert from 'const std::string [3]' to 'std::string'    
coursework_draft    C:\dev\coursework_draft\coursework_draft\coursework_draft.cpp   13
```

What do i need to change?

Comment: You can't initialize an array with another array, only elementwise. Either use a loop to copy the elements, or use `std::array` which can be copied normally.

Comment: I fixed it. Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Arrays are not copyable in C++. So this is never going to work

```
 Arguments(const string(&arg)[N]) : arguments{ arg } {}
```

You could use `std::array<std::string, N>` instead,
 or you could copy the array element by element in the body of the constructor.

Comment: fixed it. Thank you!

Comment: `Arguments(const string(&arg)[N]) : arguments( arg ) {}` seems to work also... what is wrong with it?

Comment: @Klaus It's not legal C++.  g++ is using a non-standard extension to allow it to compile

Comment: @NathanOliver: Compiles also with -pedantic which should warn on such extensions... OK, it is like it is :-) Thanks!

Comment: @Klaus Seems like a bug in GCC.

Comment: Yeah could be a bug. I can't find any mention of that in their extensions list, unless it's some weird side effect of another extension. I also can't remember this working in the past (but that might just be me)

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings: It is only 6 and a half year old. It will take some time... :-)

Answer (score 1):

This:

> ```
> arguments{ arg }
> ```

is list-initialisation and means that the first element of `arguments` is initialised with `arg`. But the elements of `arguments` are `std::string`, which cannot be initialised with an array of strings.

Arrays are not copy-initialisable.

Classes however can be copy initialisable, and they can have array members. As such, you can use a class as a wrapper around an array that can be conveniently copied. The standard library has a template for such array wrapper. Its name is `std::array`.

Another option is to copy the array in the constructor body using `std::copy` or similar function.

Comment: fixied it. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `std::copy`:

```
Arguments(const string(&arg)[N]) {
   std::copy(arg, arg + N, arguments); 
}
```

Here's a [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/bm-EFo).

Comment: i had those. the compiler said to use { } to initialize an array

Comment: This might work with g++ but it wont with clang and is not standard

Comment: @NathanOliver Oh, I didn't know that. thanks, edited.